# how to change tablayout selected text color in custom tablayout in Kotlin

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

> NewPaymentActivity

```
class NewPaymentActivity : AppCompatActivity(),SummaryFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener{


    override fun onFragmentInteraction(uri: Uri) {
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }

    internal lateinit var viewpageradapter: ViewPagerAdapter //Declare PagerAdapter

    private var tabLayout: TabLayout? = null
    var viewPager: ViewPager? = null
    var toolbar: Toolbar? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_payment)
        viewpageradapter= ViewPagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager)

        viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager) as ViewPager
        setupViewPager(viewPager!!)

        tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tab_layout) as TabLayout
        tabLayout!!.setupWithViewPager(viewPager)

      tabLayout!!.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.main));


        val headerView = (getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater)
                .inflate(R.layout.custom_tabs_for_payments, null, false)

        val receiptDetails = headerView.findViewById(R.id.tb_receipt_details) as TextView
        val paymentDetails = headerView.findViewById(R.id.tb_payment_details) as TextView
        val invoiceDetails = headerView.findViewById(R.id.tb_invoice_details) as TextView
        val summary = headerView.findViewById(R.id.tb_summary) as TextView

        tabLayout!!.getTabAt(0)!!.setCustomView(receiptDetails)
        tabLayout!!.getTabAt(1)!!.setCustomView(paymentDetails)
        tabLayout!!.getTabAt(2)!!.setCustomView(invoiceDetails)
        tabLayout!!.getTabAt(3)!!.setCustomView(summary)


    }

    private fun setupViewPager(viewPager: ViewPager) {

        val adapter = ViewPagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager)
        adapter.addFragment(ReceiptDetailsFragment(), "Receipt Details")
        adapter.addFragment(PaymentDetailsFragment(), "Payment Details")
        adapter.addFragment(InvoiceDetailsFragment(), "Invoice Details")
        adapter.addFragment(SummaryFragment(), "Summary")
        viewPager.adapter = adapter

    }

    internal inner class ViewPagerAdapter(manager: FragmentManager) : FragmentPagerAdapter(manager) {

        private val mFragmentList = ArrayList<Fragment>()
        private val mFragmentTitleList = ArrayList<String>()

        override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
            return mFragmentList[position]
        }

        override fun getCount(): Int {
            return mFragmentList.size
        }

        fun addFragment(fragment: Fragment, title: String) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment)
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title)
        }

        override fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence {
            return mFragmentTitleList[position]
        }

    }
}
```

> custom_tabs_for_payment.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/dimen_6dp"
    android:background="@color/row_gray"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tb_receipt_details"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/left_tab"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/dimen_10dp"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/dimen_6dp"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/dimen_10dp"
        android:text="Receip tDetails"

        android:textColor="@color/main"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_dimen_8sp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tb_payment_details"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/first_middle_tab"
        android:layout_weight="1"

        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/dimen_10dp"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/dimen_6dp"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/dimen_10dp"
        android:text="Payment Details"

        android:textColor="@color/main"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_dimen_8sp" />
    <TextView

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/tb_invoice_details"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/second_middle_tab"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/dimen_10dp"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/dimen_6dp"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/dimen_10dp"
        android:text="Invoice Details"

        android:textColor="@color/main"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_dimen_8sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tb_summary"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"

        android:background="@drawable/right_tab"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/dimen_10dp"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/dimen_6dp"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/dimen_6dp"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/dimen_10dp"
        android:text="Summary"
        android:textColor="@color/main"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_dimen_8sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

> I need to change my current tab layout text views according to selections.There is a way to chnage the selected tab color but I need to access custom view and chnage the text colors and text background .Below I have added current screen.I'm new to Kotlin.Thanks in advanced.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use selector color for your text view like this

> tab_text_color.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/text_selected" android:state_selected="true" /> // selected color
    <item android:color="#ababab" /> // default color
</selector>
```

and then set to your textview

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/tb_receipt_details"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        ...
        android:textColor="@color/tab_text_color"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    tabLayout!!.addOnTabSelectedListener(object : TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener {

                override fun onTabSelected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {
  receiptDetails.setTextColor(resources.getColor(R.color.white))
                    val drawable = receiptDetails.getBackground() as GradientDrawable
                    drawable.setColor(resources.getColor(R.color.received_payments))
     }
                override fun onTabUnselected(tab:TabLayout.Tab?){
                }
                override fun onTabReselected(tab:TabLayout.Tab?) {
                }
            })
```

> we can select tab using the above code and change any property from the selected tab.